How to compute Sylvester form of a matrix representing a symmetric bilinear form?
Can somebody state a step-by-step algorithm to, given a symmetric n x n-matrix A, (congruently) diagonalize A such that the entries of the diagonal are 1, -1 and 0 corresponding to the signature of A like stated in "Sylvester's law of inertia". In other words, how can I find $S\in GL_{n}(K) \ s.t. S^{T}AS=D$, where $D$ has diagonal blocks $I_{k}, -I_{l}, 0_{n-(k+l)}$. Unfortunately, until now I couldn't find a satisfactory guide for doing this.

See   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr     for how to get to diagonal  $D_1.$ The final step  is to multiply on right and left  by another diagonal matrix, call it $E.$   For each  diagonal element   $d$   of $D_1,$ the same position $e$ in matrix $E$  must be : if $d=0,  e=1.$  If $d \neq 0,$  then $e = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|d|}}$
